# javascript using object keys as variable names

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the object keys `p1`, `p2`, `p3` as variable names, but my knowledge of javascript seems insufficient to get it right. How can I do this, so in the end `console.log(p1) is value1` etc.

```
var p = {
    "p1": "value1",
    "p2": "value2",
    "p3": "value3"
};

for (var key in p) {
    if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + p[key]);
      var key = p[key]
    }
}

console.log(p1,p2,p3) //value1, value2, value3
```

Comment: This might be an X/Y problem.  Why do you want to create the variable dynamically if you're going to statically reference it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily using the global `window` object like:

```
window[key] = p[key]
```

```js
var p = {
  "p1": "value1",
  "p2": "value2",
  "p3": "value3"
};

for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    window[key] = p[key]
  }
}

console.log(p1, p2, p3)
```

Comment: @palasH Is it possible to do this without using the window object?

Answer (score -1):

In fact, you are not allowed to overwrite an object property key. I assume that's your goal by reading the `var key = p[key]` line.